# JSQLParser. How to parse an insert followed by select scope_identity()

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jsqlparser

I am using JSQLParser to select a set of SQL queries. These queries and generated by hibernate.

I have an issue when Hibernate generates an insert query followed by select scope_identity().
Because JSQLParser is parsing the insert part, and then generates an exception

```
insert into MYTABLE(LOG_ACTION, LOG_APPLICATION, LOG_CATEGORY) values (?, ?, ?) select scope_identity().
```

The following exception is thrown:
Encountered unexpected token: "select" <K_SELECT>
at line 1, column 338.

```
Was expecting one of:

","
";"
"ON"
"RETURNING"
<EOF>
```

How could I parse such a query without getting this error?

I have the following code:

```
if (sqlStatement.toLowerCase().startsWith(INSERT)) {
            return new InsertParser(sqlStatement);
```

And then in InsertParser:

```
private void preprocessInsert() {
    try {
        Insert insert = (Insert) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sqlStatement);
        // Set the table
        Table table = new Table();
        table.setName(insert.getTable().getName());
        // Now get the parameters
        List<net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.Column> columns = insert.getColumns();
        for (net.sf.jsqlparser.schema.Column column : columns) {
            Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
            mycompany.jdbc.parser.Column pColumn = new mycompany.jdbc.parser.Column();
            pColumn.setName(column.getColumnName());
            pColumn.setTable(table);
            parameter.setColumn(pColumn);
            parameters.add(parameter);
        }
    } catch (JSQLParserException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Preprocesing error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add a semicolon before the select?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this code is automatically generated by hibernate

Comment: please show the code you have already

Comment: Thank you. I have added the code in my description. At the moment I am only test if it starts by insert.  I could split the statement in two. But I have to be carefull on how I discriminate the select. Because it should work if the select was included in the "values": insert into MYTABLE(LOG_ACTION, LOG_APPLICATION, LOG_CATEGORY) values (?, select aValue from aTable, ?). If I split in two and parse only the insert that should be ok. But before doing it I'd like to know if there is no other way to achieve it